# crear una función que separe los elementos de una cadena,

Tags: r

Tengo esta base de datos y me gustaría saber como proceder en R para saber cuáles son las marcas más utilizadas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay distintas formas de lograr esto. Por ejemplo acá hay dos opciones:

**Opción 1: Usando dplyr**

```
data %>%
  separate_rows(Marcas_Usadas, sep = ", ") %>%
  group_by(Marcas_Usadas) %>%
  summarize(total = sum(!is.na(Marcas_Usadas)), .groups = "keep") %>%
  arrange(desc(total))
```

**Opción 2: Usando base R**

```
table(unlist(strsplit(data$Marcas_Usadas, ", ")))
```

**Otra Alternativa: Crear una función**

```
myfunction <- function(data){
  data %>%
    separate_rows(Marcas_Usadas, sep = ", ") %>%
    group_by(Marcas_Usadas) %>%
    summarize(total = sum(!is.na(Marcas_Usadas)), .groups = "keep") %>%
    arrange(desc(total))
}

myfunction(data)
```

**Resultado**

```
# A tibble: 6 × 2
# Groups:   Marcas_Usadas [6]
  Marcas_Usadas total
  <chr>         <int>
1 Marca2            3
2 Marca4            2
3 Marca5            2
4 Otras             2
5 Marca1            1
6 Marca3            1
```